# Find shortest path from s to every v with a limit on length

Tags: algorithm, graph, computer-science

> Let `G(V,E)` a directed graph with weights `w:E->R`. Let's assume `|V|` is dividable by `10`. Let `s` in `V`. Describe an algorithm to find a shortest path from `s` to every `v` such that it contains exactly `|V|/10` edges.

So at first I thought about using dynamic programming but I ended up with complexity of `O(|V|^3)` which apparently not optimal for this exercise.

We can't use Bellman-Ford (As far as I understand) since there might be negative cycles.

What could be an optimal algorithm for this problem?

Thanks

### EDIT

I forgot to mention a crucial information; Path can be not-simple. i.e. we may repeat edges in our path.

Comment: Could you explain your `O(|V|^3)` algorithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to me Bellman Ford's algorithm SHOULD be applicable here with a slight modification.

After iteration `k`, the distances to each node `u_j(k)` would be the shortest distance from source `s` having exactly `k` edges.

Initialize `u_j(0) = infinity` for all `u_j`, and `0` for `s`. Then recurrence relation would be,

```
u_j(k) = min {u_p(k-1) + w_{pj} | There is an edge from u_p to u_j}
```

Note that in this case `u_j(k)` may be greater than `u_j(k-1)`.

The complexity of the above algorithm shall be `O(|E|.|V|/10) = O(|E|.|V|)`.

Also, the negative cycles won't matter in this case because we shall stop after `|V|/10` iterations. Whether cost can be further decreased by adding more edges is irrelevant.

Comment: I'm sorry but I forgot to mention paths can be not-simple (i.e. can repeat edges)

Comment: I like this solution. It is essentially a Bellman-Ford using `|V|*|V|/10` memory, am I right? also I think the complexity should be `O(E*V)` instead of `O(V^2)`, right?

Comment: @Elimination That is ok, this algorithm admits that case.

Comment: @sudomakeinstall2 Yes, time complexity shall be `O(EV)`. Edited, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can perform a depth limited search with limit of `|V|/10` on your graph. It will help you find the path with the least cost.

```
limit = v_size / 10
best[v_size] initialize to MAX_INT

depth_limited(node, length, cost)
    if length == limit
        if cost < best[node]
            best[node] = cost
        return
    for each u connected to node
        depth_limited(u, length+1, cost + w[node][u])

depth_limited(start_node, 0, 0)
```

Comment: I'm  sorry, I forgot to mention the path may be not-simple (i.e. repeating edges)

Comment: This solution doesn't inhibit repeating edges.